# Pop up message that include a message and user input

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, popup

I need to create a pop up message that includes a statement and a question asking for user input. Right now I have two separate pop-ups using this code:

```
QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "Baseline", "Part {}\nThreshold: {}".format(i, threshold)) 

detect_thres, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getDouble(self,"Input Detection Threshold: ","enter a number")
```

What should I do to include both of them in the same pop-up, the message above the input dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ModelessDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, part, threshold, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Baseline")
        self.setGeometry(800, 275, 300, 200)
        self.part = part
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.threshNew = 4.4

        label    = QLabel("Part            : {}\nThreshold   : {}".format(
                                                self.part, self.threshold))
        self.label2 = QLabel("ThreshNew : {:,.2f}".format(self.threshNew))

        self.spinBox = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(-2.3)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(99)
        self.spinBox.setValue(self.threshNew)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(0.02)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChang)

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()            
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.resize(300, 200)  
        self.setLayout(layout)                                 

        okBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok) 
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self.apply)

        cancelBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        cancelBtn.clicked.connect(self.reject)              

    def apply(self):
        print("""
            Part      : {}
            Threshold : {}
            ThreshNew : {:,.2f}""".format(
                self.part, self.threshold, self.spinBox.value()))

    def valueChang(self):
        self.label2.setText("ThreshNew : {:,.2f}".format(self.spinBox.value()))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label  = QLabel('Hello Dialog', self)
        button = QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)        

    def showDialog(self):
        self.dialog = ModelessDialog(2, 55.77, self)
        self.dialog.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(300, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]